# Book Later option for Uber API

Tags: java, uber-api

For Uber Rider API Integration referring to https://developer.uber.com/docs could not find any option for book later functionality although it is available in Uber App. Am I missing something from the docs or is uber restricting this functionality to Uber App only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a scheduled ride functionality in the Uber rides API.